# Remove text always different with innerHTML (no Jquery)

Tags: javascript

My website have a page which import (using a dedicated widget) Ical feed coming from remote server. I cannot customize the output of this feed and my goal was to remove some specific text. I was able to remove "some text5" because it is always the same but I wondering how to do for remove the whole text before "Reservation". Due to the fact this text will be always different I suppose is not possible, however it should contain always the same number of characters, so maybe is possible to count the number of character before "Reservation" for remove it.

```
    <table class="contentpaneopen" style="border:0px">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="headingrow">
    <tr>
    <tr valign="top" align="left">
    <td colspan="4">
    Status: Verified + Confirmed, Duration: 2013-11-19 09:00 - 09:30, Reservation ID: R1580
    <br>
    some text1
    <br>
    some text2
    <br>
    some text3
    <br>
    some text4
    <br>
    some text5
    <br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'm a very JS newbie and I don't have idea how to do.. Any clue?

http://jsfiddle.net/w2cfh/

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to remove what's before and after Reservation ID. In that case, a regular expression is simplest way to do it (http://jsfiddle.net/w2cfh/1/):

```
document.body.innerHTML =
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/^[\w\W]*(Reservation ID: .+)[\w\W]*$/, '$1');
```

Comment: *"...remove the whole text before "Reservation"."* And that sort of `.innerHTML` replacement should be avoided.

Comment: Sorry in fact I foolishly translated the text because is french. So of course your regex solution cannot work. I updated the Fiddle..could you please adapt it? http://jsfiddle.net/w2cfh/2/

Comment: Not that hard to do. Just replace Reservation ID with Numéro de réservation: http://jsfiddle.net/w2cfh/3/